# SQLite3: Find match of a certain part of column value by regular expression and replace it with another value.

Tags: sql, regex, sqlite

I'm an absolute beginner at SQL. I do know how to use SQL commands that belong to Data Manipulation Language and Data Definition Language.

The name of the table is `ways_tags`

```
id,key,value,type

164931009,street,6th Main Road Ram Nagar (N) Extn,addr
```

The header represents the column names, I've printed just one row.

**Here's what I want to accomplish:**

1. Select observations that have `type` as `addr` and `key` as `street`.
2. In such observations, scan the characters of `value` column and check if the last 4 characters match `Extn` and replace it with `Extension`

**Also, is there a way I can reduce size of the code, where it checks for TWO patterns instead of ONE?**

In other words

**You can replace what I'd like to accomplish on 2. with something like**

2. In such observations, scan the characters of `value` column:

   i. If last 4 characters in the `value` column is `Extn` replace with    `Extension`.

   ii.If last 2 characters in the `value` column is `St.` replace with    `Street`.

I'm really sorry, but I just know the pseudocode and don't know how to incorporate regular expressions with normal SQL, and so I can't post anything to show that I've tried.

So eventually after performing the step,

```
164931009,street,6th Main Road Ram Nagar (N) Extension,addr
```

is the updated observation instead of

```
164931009,street,6th Main Road Ram Nagar (N) Extn,addr
```

Comment: Do you want to query the table with the values changed, or update the table and correct the value data?

Comment: Update it with values changed.

Answer (score 1):

> Select observations that have `type` as `addr` and `key` as `street`.
>   … scan the characters of `value` column and check if the last 4 characters match `Extn`

```
WHERE type = 'addr'
  AND key = 'street'
  AND value LIKE '%Extn'
```

> … and replace it with `Extension`

If "`Extn`" does not occur anywhere else in the value, this could be done with [replace()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace), but in the general case, you have to [extract](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) all but the four last characters, and append the new value:

```
substr(value, 1, length(value) - 4) || 'Extension'
```

Then plug this into an UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE ways_tags
SET value = substr(value, 1, length(value) - 4) || 'Extension'
WHERE type = 'addr'
  AND key = 'street'
  AND value LIKE '%Extn';
```

Doing two replacements in a single statement would be possible with a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case), but would not reduce code size.